# Old schematic sign "OVEN"

Tags: resistors, schematics

What does that "OVEN" sign mean?

This is from an audio compressor [NTP 179-130](http://gyraf.dk/schematics/NTP_179-140_Manual.pdf) schematic.

[image: NTP 179-130]

Comment: Where did the circuit come from and what is the circuit used for?

Comment: this is an NTP 179-130 schematic, and it is an audio compressor... :)

Answer (score 11):

If you look at the PCB layout in the [179-140 instruction manual for compressor amplifier 179-130](http://gyraf.dk/schematics/NTP_179-140_Manual.pdf) on page 9 you'll see R56 close by Q1 like this: -

[image]

And I suspect that Q1 has a heater coil around it that may be called "OVEN". Q1 is a JFET that is used to control the amplitude of the signal (hence form a compressor) and although the heating side of things isn't totally clear, I believe that it is warmed either to enhance the compression circuit (deeper compression) or to keep the circuit stable in different ambient temperatures. Q1 and "OVEN" connection (page 8 of the linked document): -

[image]

Comment: beat me to it, and also have the right figures! Noice.

Comment: wow. thanks a lot!!! so accordingly this component is very important.. is that available nowadays? if it isn't, is it replaceable?

Comment: @KevinKovács I think the issue is trying to find technical details about the coil that wraps around the transistor Q1. As to how important it is, that's debatable. Looking at the circuit, I don't see a great deal of reason behind keeping the JFET at a controlled temperature - It's the same sort of circuit as used in a wien bridge (for example) oscillator for keeping amplitude stability and no designs I've seen felt they needed to keep the JFET temperature stable. It might be a design whim!

Answer (score 11):

Warning upfront: Service manuals of audio equipment often contain slightly manipulated schematics to at least stop the most incompetent counterfeiters. Don't assume everything in the schematic makes sense.

but here: the symbol is that of a variable resistor.

So, either this is just a variable resistor to set the power of an oven attached to (K) and (O), or, and that looks more likely seeing the thing is flanked by 5.6 Ω resistors on both sides, **is** an oven.

Ovens are used to keep components at a stable temperature, e.g. oscillators ("OCXO": Oven-controlled crystal oscillator. Used in cases where you need a very stable oscillator and don't care too much about power consumption.), or maybe a semiconductor that needs to be kept at the right temperature to behave like the device requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a component oven - its purpose is to keep the (highly selected) attenuation JFET at a constant temperature (80°C IIRC) - in order to keep its electrical parameters from drifting with ambient temperature, like the OCXO mentioned above.